# Why cant I override theme_form_element_label in drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal, overriding

I'm trying to customize form label output in Drupal 7.12 branch and I cannot figure out what is wrong and why is this function cannot be overridden.

here is example of my template.php

```
function myThemeName_form_element($variables)
{
    var_dump(__FUNCTION__);
    return theme('form_element_label', $variables);
}

function myThemeName_form_element_label($variables)
{
    var_dump(__FUNCTION__);
}
```

As result I can only see `myThemeName_form_element` as output, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try overriding just `theme_form_element_label()`?

Comment: I managed to pass this issue, as it was caused by caching mechanism, I did not know that you have to empty cache every time you introduce new override method to your template.

Comment: Drupal caches the theme functions implemented by a theme. If you are editing an enabled theme, you need to clear the cache, or disable (and then re-enable) the theme. In the latter case, you are forcing Drupal to clear the cache it uses.